# How to migrate linq to sql for sqlce to sqlite?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a project with SQL Server CE as the database using Linq-to-SQL.

How can I replace SQL Server CE with another DBMS? (preferably SQLite)

I looked around the net for some info but nothing about replacing an RDBMS in a Linq-to-SQL scenario.

Best regards and thanks in advance!

Salih Goncu

Editing to reflect the comments:

The name of the product is "SQL Server Compact Edition" if you want the full name, or if abbreviated form is preferred, then SQL CE, as the Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition team prefers to use in their own blog. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlservercompact/

Second, Linq to Sql is not specific to SQL Server only. It is supported by many different RDBMS, including SQLite. The annoying fact is, when you create your schema, a code behind is also generated and there are SQL statements auto-generated in that code behind which needs to be converted. Doing that manually is tedious.

My revised question is, "is there an easy way of doing this conversion process?"

Thank you very much.

Comment: Linq-to-SQL is for SQL Server **only** - if you need support for various databases, use Entity Framework instead

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to install this package to make linq work with sqlite?
https://www.nuget.org/packages/linq2db.SQLite/